# When would I get online flag as true for a user?

Tags: ios, soundcloud

I want to know when would I get the "online" flag as true for a user? I am logged in to my soundcloud account through the browser as well as through the mobile app, but I still get online flag as false. I am using the API endpoint `http://api.soundcloud.com/users/{id}.json?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID` to get the user details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this flag is no longer used due to it having inaccurate information.  See the post [Where did 'Who's Online' go?](http://help.soundcloud.com/customer/portal/articles/1485216-where-did-who-s-online-go-) from SoundCloud Help.

Comment: Thanks JAL for the answer.