# How to find when soundcloud user was last active using API

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, soundcloud

I'm trying to figure out what the "last-modified" field indicates on user pages. It has only updated when I changed my profile information, but I'd like to know if there is a way to figure out when a user was last active?

Answer (score 0):

That level of user information is not available via the API, likely for privacy reasons. There is an `online` boolean field available for the `/users` endpoint, which appears to show the user's online status.

Comment: The `online` hasn't been accurate in years.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26124721/2415822)